# É possível desabilitar o transaction log no Sybase Anywhere 9?

Tags: banco-de-dados

É possível desabilitar o transaction log no `Sybase Anywhere 9`. Desabilitar para uma tabela em específico?

Comment: Podes dizer qual a razao pelo qual queres desactivar o transaction log?

Comment: O motivo é que em meu banco possuo uma tabela transitória, a qual não há necessidade de ser registrada no transaction log.  É possivel inserir dados nessa tabela sem modificar o transaction log? Utilizo o Sybase Anywhere 9.

Comment: Pela informação que tenho não penso que seja possível desactivar o transaction log apenas para uma tabela. Penso que seja configurado ao nível da base de dados.